Get the list of questions upvoted by me using OAuth & API
I'm using Stackexchange-API in one of my apps and I want to get a list of questions that a user has Upvoted.
I have already implemented OAuth in the app and use the API calls with a token, so the Upvotes can be returned. I'm already using the token in the /questions/{ids} to get if the question is upvoted or not and I'm successful in that.
So, currently I'm fetching if the user has upvoted the question or not using the /questions/{ids} API where I already know the question ids.
But now I want to get a list of questions that the user has upvoted. And since

these will not be posted by the user themselves, I cannot use users/{ids}/questions
I don't know the list of questions ids already, I cannot use /questions/{ids}

How can I do this?

Edit
To be clear, this is NOT a question to identify "WHO voted on my posts", it is to identify "WHAT posts have I voted"
This is possible using the access token as mentioned in the documentation here

The upvoted, downvoted, and favorited fields can only be queried for with an access_token with the private_info scope.


see: See who is upvoting/ downvoting my question/answer  AND/OR  Is there a way to see who voted on your posts?

I’m voting to close this question because there was not done some basic research.

@Luuk The linked questions in the above comment and what I'm asking are not the same. Like I mentioned in the question already - I already am able to figure out if I have upvoted a question or not using the /questions/{ids}. To be clear - this question is an OAuth question - using which you can identify upvotes as mentioned in the documentation. I have added an edit highlighting the documentation as well for your reference.

I voted to close because of "a list of questions that a user has Upvoted.", your EDIT made the question a bit more clear...

This can't be done via the Stack Exchange API. You can scrape the upvote page in your profile to achieve your goal.
